# TCP/IP Socket Random Disconnection and Calling a synchronous method inside asynchronous method

Tags: c#, async-await, tcpclient, tcplistener

Application component is connected to server and getting data over TCP/IP socket connection. My delegate method of client fires whenever I received message/data from server as below.

```
public async Task OnMessage(byte[] message)
{
    var Message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
    Console.WriteLine(Message);
            
    ProcessMessages(Message); ////  Synchronous method can be long running depending upon the message content.
}
```

If my method ProcessMessages is synchronous calling inside an asynchronous method. Does it blocks the other messages to be received while ProcessMessages method is calling or executing?

Please note: It can take few seconds to process message depending upon some messages nature. Does my socket connection with server breaks in this case, even though heartbeat sent to server over each 3 seconds interval?

Can you please explain the  OnMessage() in TCP/IP connection failure reason or disconnection whereas there is no network disconnection observed.

Answer (score 1):

`async` won't make a method run in the background. It's syntactic sugar that allows the use of `await` to await already asynchronous operations. It tells the compiler to generate the state machine needed to handle `await`.

To process the message in another thread use `Task.Run`, eg  :

```
public async Task OnMessage(byte[] message)
{
    var Message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
    Console.WriteLine(Message);
            
    await Task.Run(()=>ProcessMessages(Message));
}
```